# QA Report in Python needs to compare and identify mismatches between two dataframes in multiple column pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with two data frames with the same column structure that share a a primary identifier. The data in both files looks like this:

Table 1:

```
Product_ID    Number_of_Parts   Number_In_Stock      Product_SKU
A                4                    4                  BCS
B                3                    5                  PLA
C                1                    8                  RED
J                5                    9                  GEN
```

Table 2:

```
Product_ID    Number_of_Parts  Number_In_Stock      Product_SKU
A                   4                 4               BCS
B                   1                 5               PLA
C                   1                 6               RED
D                   3                 2               FRA
```

I want to produce a report for all IDs between the two dataframes that identifies the following:

1. IDs that are in Table 1, but not in Table 2
2. IDs that are in Table 2, but not in Table 1
3. Product ID value mismatches across all column pairs. Something like the below would be ideal:

QA Report:

```
Product_ID     Issue                     Value in Table 1     Value in Table 2
B              Number_of_Parts Mismatch         3                    1
C              Number_In_Stock Mismatch         8                    6
J              In Table 1, not Table 2          
D              In Table 2, not Table 1
```

The actual number of columns for comparison is close to 10 so ideally the column comparison can be a for loop of some sort to iterate over all column pairs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something that should definitely help you get started is the `isin()` function. For example:

```
In [17]: table1[~table1['Product_ID'].isin(table2['Product_ID'])]
Out[17]:
  Product_ID  Number_of_Parts  Number_In_Stock Product_SKU
3          J                5                9         GEN
```

Or a combination of conditions:

```
In [19]: table1[(table1['Product_ID'].isin(table2['Product_ID'])) & (table1['Number_of_Parts'] != table2['Number_of_Parts'])]
Out[19]:
  Product_ID  Number_of_Parts  Number_In_Stock Product_SKU
1          B                3                5         PLA
```

You can run these queries and use the results to build the full report dataframe.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This is great thanks. I am trying to implement and getting data back, but unsure of how to build in a loop for this and then store the rows that meet each criteria in a dataframe in the format of the QA report example table. Any other helpful hints to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You don't need to do it with a loop. Basically you are testing for 4 different cases, each case with different conditions. You can store the results of filtering for each case in a dataframe, and then manipulate each dataframe to add the columns and values you need, (e.g. for case 1 you would add a column `Issue` and populate it with `In table 1 and not table 2`, etc.), and then use `append()` to append the four dataframes to one big report dataframe.